# CSS3 Animation: Forwards fill not working with position and display on Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-animations

So, I have created a CSS3 animation that is supposed to fade out an element by setting its opacity from 1 to 0 and at the last frames change the `position` to `absolute` and `display` to `none`. But on Safari it will only maintain the opacity, position and display are not set to the final values.

```
@-webkit-keyframes impressum-fade-out {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
  }
  99% {
    opacity: 0;
    position: relative;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
  }
}
```

It seems to work on Chrome but not on Safari (I tried version 8). Apparently, position and display do not work properly with animation-fill-mode: forwards...

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uhtL12gv/

**EDIT For Bounty:** I am aware of workarounds with Javascript and transitionend events. But I am wondering why Browsers lack support for this? Does the specification state that fillmode forwards doesnt apply to some attributes like position or is this a bug in the browsers? Because I couldnt find anything in the bug trackers.. If anybody has some insight, I would really appreciate it

Comment: Your fiddle does not seem to be working :/

Comment: It works equally in Chrome and Safari on OS X, the latest versions of all. `display: none` and `position: absolute` don't apply at the last frame.

Comment: But `display:none` and `position:absolute` *should* be applied because they are defined in the 100% frame... Also, it's working on my Chrome 45, but not in Chrome 44 ...

Comment: As it seems that display and position do not apply in most browsers, would it be enough if you set the animated element to width/height = 0 on the last frame?

Comment: @TimoD why do you want only solution based on `animation-fill-mode: forwards`? You use jQuery anyway for change state. Are you not interested in browsers that don't support `transition`/`animation`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Suggested in the comments, you can adjust the height.

**EDIT:** Animation Reference Links Added.

- [Display property is not animatable.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)
- [Position property is not
  animatable.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)
- [List of all CSS properties and if and how they are
  animatable.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties)

```js
$('.block').click(function() { $(this).toggleClass('active') });
```

```css
@-webkit-keyframes impressum-fade-out {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  99% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    height:0;  
  }
}

.block {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
}

.block2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;    
}

.block.active {
  -webkit-animation-name: impressum-fade-out;
        animation-name: impressum-fade-out;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 500ms;
        animation-duration: 500ms;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block2"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The solution with height does not work for my directly because of how my elements are structured. However, The links in your edit is exactly what I was looking for. So I guess the reason why this did not work is because position and display are not animatable.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you the cross-browser solution based on [CSS3 Transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) and [transitionend](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/Events/transitionend) event:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sergdenisov/005y6jdk/)

```js
$('.block').one('click', function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    $this.one('webkitTransitionEnd transitionend', function() {
        $this.addClass('block_hidden');
        $this.removeClass('block_transition');
    });

    $this.addClass('block_transition');
});
```

```css
.block {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: blue;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

    .block_2 {
        background: red;    
    }

    .block_transition {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    .block_hidden {
        display: none;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block block_2"></div>
```